# Ionic Toggle button disable and enable not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
    <ion-toggle ng-model="this.customerchecked" toggle-class="toggle-calm" ng-disabled="this.one || this.two" ng-change="customerEngaged()"> Customer Engaged </ion-toggle>

    <div class="list card">
    <ion-toggle ng-model="this.one" toggle-class="toggle-calm" ng-change="oneChange()"> One </ion-toggle>

    <ion-toggle ng-model="this.two" toggle-class="toggle-calm" ng-change="twoChange()"> Two </ion-toggle>
</div>
```

Comment: can provide your full html with controller declaration part ?

Comment: could you elaborate the issue

Comment: When i On the  toggle one then customer toggle is get disabled.But when i Off it then the disabled customer toggle is not getting enabled.

Answer (score 0):

if you want that ion-toggle will be disabled, you need that one be true or two will true, so if you want that ion-toggle will be enabled, you need that one be false **and** two be false

Comment: i am applying the same but its not working on device

Comment: Samsung DUOS (SM-G530H)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  <ion-toggle ng-model="data.toggleOne" 
>    ng-true-value="'varTrue'" 
>    ng-false-value="'varFalse'"
>    ng-change="toggleServiceState(data.toggleOne)"
>    toggle-class="toggle-calm">Name of Toggle</ion-toggle>
> ```

If "this.one" is simple type like string, int etc Using it and change from controller it's not so simple if You want use dual-data binding in ionic (and ofc angular ) you have to remember that simple type not working with it (it have to object). When you put each toggle value into object you can change it (with UI change from controller site)